# Can`t access database while creating migrations

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, database-connection

When i try to enable migrations i keep getting this error

"An error occurred accessing the database. This usually means that the connection to the database failed. Check that the connection string is correct and that the appropriate DbContext constructor is being used to specify it or find it in the application's config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386386 for information on DbContext and connections. See the inner exception for details of the failure."

Is it something wrong with my connection string?

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="vAirLine" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=vAirline; Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

and this is my dbcontext:

```
 public class vAirlineDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
    {
        public vAirlineDbContext()
            : base("vAirLine", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }       

        public static vAirlineDbContext Create()
        {
            return new vAirlineDbContext();
        }

        public DbSet<Plane> Planes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Flight> Flights { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Seat> Seats { get; set; }       
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw this a few times before, check that the database instance is running, mine had stopped for some reason, restart it and everything was fine

Comment: how to check that? in server explorer i also cant open there("Cannot open database "vAirline" requested by the login. The login failed.")

Comment: try 'sqllocaldb info' at the command line. this wuaestion talks about restarting it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287252/cannot-start-localdb

Comment: It started to work again on its own, i didnt change a thing... weird.