# SQL Server 2012 Express error: can not connect and start local db

Tags: sql-server, localdb

I have installed SQL Server 2012 Express version where I have a local db instance separately. When I connect to SQL Server Express, it connected without problem, but when I try to connect to local db, I get the following error:

> The attempt to attach to the database failed with the following information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:2)
> The system cannot find the file specified.

When I open SQL Server Configuration Manager, the local db service is not running but it is stopped. When I start that  it shows error

> The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion. Consult the event log or other applicable error logs for details

When I open its properties and select log on as built in with local system after clicking apply it shows error

> The process terminated unexpectedly.[0x8007042b].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287252/cannot-start-localdb

Comment: Although LocalDB is lightweight IMHO it seems to suffer a lot more install and configuration isues than SQL Express does

Comment: What does the Windows Application event log say?